# Git graph: develop branch shown as linear instead of as a diverged branch of master (that I think)

Tags: git, git-branch

I have two branches: `master` & `develop`. `Develop` diverges from `master` after the second commit on master and has own 3 commits. However the graph in `gitk` as well as in command line is shown as linear as below:

[image: In Gitk]

[image]

I believe it should resemble more like a branch something like the below:

[image]

I am still learning the basics and not even sure whether my interpretation of what a branched graph should look like is even the right way or not.

thanks
app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have not "diverged" in the sense that there has been no parallel work on `master`. `master` still contains a subset of the changes on `develop`. There is no value at all in rendering a curved line in this case.

The graph you're expecting to see will only occur if *both* branches contain commits after the point at which they diverge. If you add a commit on `master`, Git (and gitk) will render the graph with a fork in.

Answer (score 3):

What's the difference between a donut and a coffee cup?

[To a *topologist*, they are the same thing!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mug_and_Torus_morph.gif)  (Which is why topologists keep trying to dunk their coffee mugs into their donuts.)

This same idea holds for Git commit graphs as well.  There's no difference between:

```
o--o--o
       \
        o--o--o
```

and the straight-line version of the same graph: they represent the same graph either way.

Answer (score 1):

Both pics show the same thing. When you create a branch on git (unlike, say, svn), there's no new revision being created. It's just a new pointer to a revision (the same one master was on when the other branch was created). You start committing on the other branch, it's a linear flow. If you then commit *something else* on master, you would be able to see the branches diverge. Think of it this way: forget about where master is. If you wanted to see the history of the other branch, it would be a straight sequence of revisions. But then master is a *pointer* to one of those revisions.