# why all the commits and branches are shown in a straight forwarding line after git merge

Tags: git, github

as a sample i take these steps :

```
git branch -b newFeature
git add -A
git commit -m `my feature added`
git checkout master
git merge newFeature
```

when i do `git branch` the branches are listed correctly 
i expect the branches to be like this : 
[image: branching] 
1.why all the commits and branches are shown in a straight forwarding line?
[image: git]
2.how to achieve the mentioned branching?

Comment: The second tree view is just showing something else than your `new-feature` branch... why would you expect it to display the same? Start by making both point at the same commit/branch, so you can compare displays.

Comment: @RomainValeri thats an example, 
you can have a look to @M Imam Pratama answer to get the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`git merge` will do fast-forward (`--ff`) merge when possible by default](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---ff). A fast-forward merge is possible when the two branches are not [diverged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572842/9157799). To get the branch graph like you expected, use `--no-ff`:

```
git merge --no-ff newFeature
```

From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---no-ff):

> With `--no-ff`, create a merge commit in all cases, even when the merge could instead be resolved as a fast-forward.

Comment: thanks! also [this page of the doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) is plain and legible !

Answer (score 1):

### What happens when you merge?

Git merge by default makes a new commit that has 2 parent commits, this is called a **merge commit**. These parents are the latest commit from the two branches you're trying to merge. This merge commit will contain all the changes made in the two branches. That is the point of merging to bring content together from two commits.

### Why did your branches not merge?

In your case since you've not commited anything to master, your branches did not diverge. This makes merging pointless as you can just **fast-forward** main to the new branch so git will be smart enough to do just that. This way you'll have the contents of both branches in one commit.

**Fast-forwarding** a branch simply means that you move the branch pointer (because a branch is just a pointer to a commit) up to the new commit. This way master will contain all changes from both itself and your second branch, hence the needlessness of merging.

As M Imam Pratama pointed out you can use the `--no-ff`
option to create a merge commit.